# Sitecore web forms module redirect to secure page

Tags: wffm

I am using sitecore 7.2 and web forms module and I am not using MVC.
I have a secured page that only authenticated users can access.
If user tries to access this page, he is sent to the login page, this login page has form built using the form module and on submission I am using "Login with password" action provided by the forms module.

Login is successful but user is not redirected to the secured page, page refreshes and shows the login form again but no redirect is happening.
If I change the redirect page to a non secure page, it works fine.

Comment: Please elaborate on your Sitecore, WFFM version. Are you using WFFM MVC. Can you add information from log files? Check security permissions to your secured page. Does logged in user role have read access to the secured page?

Comment: sitecore version added, yes page is secured and only authenticated users can access, after login action, it should technically log me in and I should be able to access the secure page but somehow it shows I am not logged in properly and redirects me back to the login page with returnurl in the query string.

Comment: Can you please ensure that you have selected Redirect option when you configured Save action on the form button?

Comment: yes, if I redirect to a non secure page, it works fine.

Comment: Did you see any exceptions in log files? If you won't mind can you attach screenshot of your forms designer and how you configured. Provide as much information as you can.